# Scaling arguments for the flow around a cylinder OUTSIDE the Boundary Layer

Tags: fluid-dynamics, normalization, scaling

For a two-dimensional, laminar, incompressible, and steady flow around a non-rotating cylinder with $Re_x\gg1$ how would I determine the scaling arguments for $x$, $y$, $u_x$, and $u_y$ **outside** of the boundary layer $(y>\delta)$? The coordinates $x$ and $y$ are defined as $$x=R\theta$$ $$y=r-R$$ where $R$ is the radius of the cylinder and $r$ is the distance measured from its center. **Inside** the boundary layer $(y<\delta)$, the scaling would be as follows $$x\propto R$$ $$y\propto \delta$$ $$u_x\propto V_0$$ where $V_0$ is the free-stream velocity and the velocity just outside the boundary layer. The scaling for $u_y$ is derived from the other three using the continuity equation resulting in $u_y\ll u_x$. Considering the region **outside** of the boundary layer again $(y>\delta)$, my guess would be that the only change would be $y\propto R$ which would give $u_y\propto V_0$. However, this doesn't seem correct to me since I believe the perpendicular component $u_y\ll u_x$ although maybe not to the same degree as in the boundary layer.

I would appreciate some clarification on the reasoning for the scaling arguments both **inside** and **outside** the boundary layer.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have misunderstood the application of scaling arguments. $x,y,$ are independent variables, and can take any value in the fluid domain. Statements such as $x~\alpha ~R,y~\alpha~\delta,$ are meaningless in this context.

The correct way to do it is to begin with an equation, such as for example continuity equation:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=0
\end{align}
and substitute estimates for the *derivatives* in that equation. In a boundary layer $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\sim\frac{U}{R}$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\sim\frac{V}{\delta}$, where $V$ is the scale for change in vertical velocity across the boundary layer. The statement $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\sim\frac{U}{R}$ means that horizontal velocity changes by an amount $U$ over a horizontal distance $R$ in the boundary layer.

Once you go outside the boundary layer the derivatives in the continuity equation must be estimated differently. Sufficiently far from the cylinder the flow is uniform and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\approx 0$, which implies that $\frac{U}{R}$ is a bad estimate for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$; horizontal flow velocity shall change by an amount $U$ over a distance $L$ very much larger than $R$ (i.e. $L\gg R$), so that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\sim\frac{U}{L}$. But pursuing this analysis further is not useful because you don't have an estimate for either $L$ or the derivative $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ (except knowing that it must also be $\approx 0$) in terms of given parameters of the problem (such as $R,U,$ and fluid properties).

Comment: thank you for the response. I've always seen this presented by starting from the scaling parameters and then using continuity; not the other way around. I guess my question is dealing more with the estimation process of the derivatives than anything else, specifically how to arrive at them and how they change at different positions in and out of the boundary layer. I can edit my question if you think that would help.

Comment: @NWernerC456 Do edit the question if you wish make it more precise.